# MYSQL - select element inside array from database

Tags: mysql

I need to export a csv file from phpmyadmin that is filtered to some degree.

My Table looks like this

```
        ID  |  Name  | Email | Price
     29817  |  Firstname LastName  | Random@email.com | 
{"subtotal":{"1":774,"0":730.18867924528},
"discount":{"1":70,"0":66.037735849057},
"shipping":{"1":59,"0":55.660377358491},
"handling":{"1":0,"0":0},
"printer":{"1":288.75,"0":231}
}
```

I Need to select the subtotal of this this column and i've tried multiple ways to do this and ofcourse have googled around a lot. I can't seem to find any good information about this and was wondering how you can do this with only SQL no PHP

So far i've tried this

```
SELECT name, email, id 
FROM order_pending
WHERE country = 'se'
AND price['subtotal'] > 2000
```

and Also This

```
SELECT name, email, id 
FROM order_pending
WHERE country = 'se'
AND price.subtotal > 2000
```

I get syntax error in the sql and i don't know how to do a correct search inside an array.

Comment: `MySQL` understands what you saved in `Price` column is a string but not an array. Hence your query won't work. And Array based querying is not supported...

Comment: country? Is it in another table or it is a typo?

Comment: `subtotal`, `discount`, `shipping`, `handling` and `printer` should all be separate columns in your table. Or, a separate `Price` table that is joined by a key to your first tables. Arrays are a bad idea in RDBMS.

Comment: Do you only need to select the subtotal?

Comment: Since there is about 6000 rows or more it's kinda to late to change the structure of the table. Since it seems like Mysql handles the array as a string i think i'll try to compare the id och the user with other tables, i found a payment table that i can use via an INNER JOIN.

Thanks for the answers guys i think @RavinderReddy gave me the answer i needed. I need to try a different solution.